# Not able to upload the files to S3 from react native using amplify

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I tried to upload the file to S3 Bucket using the below code

```js
RNFS.readFile(this.state.photo.uri, 'base64').then((res) => {
  Storage.put(filename, base64.decode(res)).then((stored) => {
    console.log('stored', JSON.stringify(stored))
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  });
}).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

It gave me  **AWSS3Provider - error uploading [Error: Request failed with status code 403]**.

But if I remove base64.decode(res) and run the below code it uploads a file on S3{this file didn't open}

```js
RNFS.readFile(this.state.photo.uri, 'base64').then((res) => {
  Storage.put(filename, res).then((stored) => {
    console.log('stored', JSON.stringify(stored))
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  });
}).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

I've to upload the image/videos directly from mobile app{React-Native} to AWS S3.

Comment: 403 means your access denied, Please check your rights and key.

Comment: @Rajan, When I tried the 2nd code it works fine.